# Why does UILabel looses it's highlighted state when it's set in story board?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uilabel

I would like my UILabel to show it's highlighted state by default.

I've set a highlighted color and enabled the Highlighted property in my story board as shown in attached screenshot.

As expected, the story board shows my label in the desired state. But, when I run the app, the label is rendered in it's default text color.

Why is "isHighlighted" not set to true when I run the app?

[image: A screenshot from Xcode that shows I have enabled Highlighted in my story board]

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: I think so too. I've filed a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Because this doesn't affect the app while running. The only usage is to let you see in IB the behavior when the state is selected. If you want to force the behavior at app launch use the following :

[image]

Comment: "isHighlited" doesn't work (even when spelled correctly), but "highlighted" does the trick!

Comment: Sure, once you've updated it to be correct, I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `UIButton` as a highlighted text and do not pass any touchUpInside method. It will look like highlighted `UILabel` just by setting setSelected property on.